# Divisors of prime factorizations

Tags: proof-writing, prime-factorization

Let $f,g,h \in F[x]$, with $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ relatively prime.  If $f(x)$ divides $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ divides $h(x)$ prove that $f(x)g(x)$ divides $h(x)$.

My thoughts: there are certain properties that prove that multiplied together these will divide $h(x)$.

Comment: Hint: since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime, there exist polynomials $a(x), b(x) \in F[x]$, $f(x)a(x) + g(x)b(x) = 1$. Multiply both sides by $h(x)$. Now what do you conclude?

Comment: this would put it into the form h(x)f(x)a(x)+h(x)g(x)b(x)=h(x)

Comment: Right. Since $f(x)|h(x)$, there exist $k(x) \in F[x]$ such that $h(x) = k(x)f(x)$. Similarly, since $g(x)|h(x)$, there exists $l(x) \in F[x]$ such that $h(x) = l(x)g(x)$. Hence, we have $l(x)g(x)f(x)a(x) + k(x)f(x)g(x)b(x) = h(x)$. Now factor.

Comment: you could factor out the f(x)g(x) to give you: f(x)g(x)[l(x)a(x)+k(x)b(x)]=h(x) so h(x)/(f(x)g(x))= the other factors which is in F[x] so it must be true

Answer (score 0):

If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ divide $h(x)$, $h(x)$ includes all of both of their factors. The factorization of $f(x)g(x)$ will obviously include all the factors of both. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ were not relatively prime, the factors they shared would be compounded in the factors of $f(x)g(x)$ and there is no guarantee that the factorization of $h(x)$ would include this many of these factors. However since there is no overlap between the factors of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the factors of $f(x)g(x)$ must simply be the union of the factors of each, which $h(x)$ must include.

Comment: Because $\ldots$